# I am getting an error when I am trying to runn ansible playbook that creates a ec2 security group

Tags: amazon-ec2, ansible

```
---
- hosts: localhost
  connection: local
  gather_facts: false
  tasks:
    - name: Create a security group
      ec2_group:
        - name: Ansible
          description: Ansible security group
          region: us-east-1
          rules:
            - proto: tcp
              from_port: 80
              to_port: 80
              cidr_ip: 0.0.0.0/0

            - proto: tcp
              from_port: 22
              to_port: 22
              cidr_ip: 0.0.0.0/0
```

**When I run this playbook I am getting the error below**

[root]#ansible-playbook aws1.yaml 
 ERROR! unexpected parameter type in action:

The error appears to be in '/root/Desktop/ansible_pro/aws/1/aws1.yaml': line 6, column 7, but may
be elsewhere in the file depending on the exact syntax problem.

The offending line appears to be:

```
tasks:
    - name: Create a security group
      ^ here
```

I am new with aws with ansible. Please help

Comment: Your playbook is not valid. Fix it. `ec2_group` as any other module is expecting dict keys as parameters, not a list. At the very least, you can look at the examples on the module documentation.

Answer (score 0):

@Zellounator is correct.

first you should check your playbook syntax by using below command:

```
  #ansible-playbook aws1.yaml --syntax-check
```

Then you can do dry run of same playbook:
     #ansible-playbook aws1.yaml --check

the corrected code can look like the below :

```
---
 - hosts: localhost
   connection: local
   gather_facts: false
   tasks:
 - name: Create a security group
   ec2_group:
      name: Ansible
      description: Ansible security group
      region: us-east-1
      rules:
        - proto: tcp
          from_port: 80
          to_port: 80
          cidr_ip: 0.0.0.0/0

        - proto: tcp
          from_port: 22
          to_port: 22
          cidr_ip: 0.0.0.0/0
```

and another example for the below you can allow multiple ports at a time.

```
---
- hosts: localhost
  connection: local
  gather_facts: false

  tasks:

  - name: Create a security group
    ec2_group:
     name: Ansible
     description: Ansible security group
     region: us-east-1
     rules:
      - proto: tcp
        ports:
        - 22
        - 80
        cidr_ip: 0.0.0.0/0
```

make sure you have configured IAM role or Secret key, access key which can be attached to ec2 and able to create Security group.

You can go through the example with below link:
https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/ec2_group_module.html & its always recommended to go through examples of ansible playbook.

Hope this helps.